# REST: Search results from communication sites aren't tenant wide

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience

**[edit]** Narrowing the diagnostic: searchs results are incorrect wen call from communication sites
**[/edit]**

I'm working with SharePoint Online and I'm facing an issue regarding search results.

I have two site collections. Let's say `/sites/A` and `/sites/B`

Using the Search Query Tool (2.8.3.0), I put this search : `path:"https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/A`

Running this query against `/sites/A works`. Same query against `/sites/B` *does not*.

However, (and it's puzzling me), the other direction works. Search for `path:"https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/B` **works** against the two collections.

What can explain this behavior?

If it matters, here's the higher picture : we have a site hub (which is /A in my case) and a bunch of sites collections (/B) joined to the hub. All of theses sites are modern team sites. The hub site is a communication site. Each site have a unique "metadata" item in a specific list. Then I want to search for these items using the modern search web parts from the hub site.

Comment: Do you have any Search Settings, like query rules or others configurations that differ between the sites? You can export the config and compare to see.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: as I said I'm testing from Search Query Tool. Unless i'm wrong the SQT doesn't use rules? That said, I don't have customization of rules

Comment: I narrowed the diagnostic. The issue occurs on all communication sites, never on team sites. Observed on two different tenants

Comment: I would just specify the tenant root or the tenant Enterprise Search Center `/search/` for your API calls. Then you can control the outcome.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: even if it works, I won't be able to solve my actual problem which is to use the modern search webparts. These components are executing the search onto the current site.

Comment: Steve, did you overcome this ?.. I am facing exactly same thing

Comment: @KunalValecha: unfortunately no :(

Comment: @SteveB - Thanks for reply.  I got this working by adding EnableDynamicGroups:true in my api call = /_api/search/query?querytext='something'&Properties='EnableDynamicGroups:true'"

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting, to change the search scope while searching on a modern site.
But, this doesn't work trough the REST API it seems.

See also: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Configure-modern-search-results-to-search-all-of-your/m-p/447334/highlight/false#M29047